# What's this Marvel story where a villain escapes from prison

Tags: story-identification, marvel

I read this Marvel story long ago (early 90's). If I remember correctly it involved Fantastic Four and some villain who created some kind of an artificial man (that looked like a scare crow or otherwise a bit weird) to help him escape from a prison.

I think at one point the artificial character had jumped through the bars in the prison cell, causing the guards to think that it was the villain escaping although the villain may still have been inside the prison.

What story was this and who was the villain?

Comment: Going to have to give us a bit more to go on. Were there any guest stars, costume colors, locations, story arcs which can help us narrow down the 75 years of Marvel continuity we have to sort through?